# Trouble with "<" in php echo

Tags: php, echo

I'm developing a UVa-like website, where users can submit their source code to solve a problem. However, I'm storing their submitted source code so that they can later see their source code. My mySql server is holding them fine. But using php when I echo them, it is not displaying the way it should. For example let's say I have The following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
 if(5<6)printf("don't joke with me...");
}
```

When I echo it from the database it just shows as below :

```
#include 
    int main(){
     if(5
    }
```

So, I figure out that when ever it finds "<" and after that does not show anything after that.
How can I fix the issue. Any suggestion will be appreciated ......

Comment: Check the source of the HTML you're generating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are displaying it in the browser. You need to escape the characters that have a special meaning in html.

See also for the function `htmlspecialchars()`: http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 1):

When you echo the string use htmlentities().

`echo htmlentities($value_from_database);`

I expect the browser is picking up the first < as the opening of an html tag.

Comment: Well, this is fine too; but there's any difference (to htmlspecialchars()) in what is displayed when encodings are set correctly. (and htmlentities makes source code less readable too.)